# Message Box with Qt

Tags: qt, arm, ubuntu-16.04, qdialog, qmessagebox

I have real time operating system running QT application in real time environment. I want to display message on my embedded device which will be waiting for user input and i do not want to block my remaining functionality in the same thread.

Please share your ideas/ example for displaying non blocking message box.

Thanks,
Mrudula

Comment: You can use https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#open - QMessageBox inherits from QDialog

Answer (score 0):

QWidgets including dialogs do not necessarily block.

```
Dia::Dia(QWidget *parent) : 
    QWidget(parent) 
{
    this->setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt::Dialog);
```

If I call

```
_dia = new Dia(mainParent);
_dia->show()
```

My underlying context does not get blocked.